# Digital root recursive algorithm

Tags: recursion

There is a lot of ways to find a digital root of a number and they are all similar to each other, but I can't understand the following one:

```
int digitalRoot(int n)
   if (n < 10)
      return n;
   else
      return digitalRoot(n / 10 + n % 10);
```

I see what the algorithm does, but can't understand why it works, how digital root of a number is related to sum of *n / 10 + n % 10*. Maybe someone could explain it to me in simple terms if there is a simple explanation?

I'm hard to see any relations between the following ways of getting the digital root, but they give the same result and that's exactly what I'm trying to understand..

1. 1729 => 1 + 7 + 2 + 9 = 19
2. 19 => 1 + 9 = 10
3. 10 => 1 + 0 = 1

and

1. 1729 => 172 + 9 = 181
2. 181 => 18 + 1 = 19
3. 19 => 1 + 9 = 10
4. 10 => 1 + 0 = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an example explains better:
Let `n` be 1234
First call to function returns `123 + 4`
Now `n=127`, second call returns `12 + 3+4`
Now `n=19`, third call returns `1 + 2+3+4`
The result is `1` after fourth call.
So, it basically adds up all the digits.

Comment: I like your example. I think I almost get the idea. I just need to play with other numbers to feel comfortable with it. Thank you!